# Quick matrix transpose with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What's the underscore.js equivalent for a quick matrix transpose, such as this one in Python:

```
orig = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(zip(*orig))
# [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

I don't believe Javascript has positional argument expansion, so what's the quickest way to feed this to `_.zip([])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
orig = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
_.zip.apply(_, orig);
```